# A zero-indexed array given & An equilibrium index of this array

Tags: java, c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

A zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. An equilibrium index of this array is any integer P such that 0 ≤ P < N and the sum of elements of lower indices is equal to the sum of elements of higher indices, i.e. 
A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[P−1] = A[P+1] + ... + A[N−2] + A[N−1].
Sum of zero elements is assumed to be equal to 0. This can happen if P = 0 or if P = N−1.

For example, consider the following array A consisting of N = 8 elements:

```
  A[0] = -1
  A[1] =  3
  A[2] = -4
  A[3] =  5
  A[4] =  1
  A[5] = -6
  A[6] =  2
  A[7] =  1
```

P = 1 is an equilibrium index of this array, because:

```
A[0] = −1 = A[2] + A[3] + A[4] + A[5] + A[6] + A[7]
```

P = 3 is an equilibrium index of this array, because:

```
A[0] + A[1] + A[2] = −2 = A[4] + A[5] + A[6] + A[7]
```

P = 7 is also an equilibrium index, because:

```
A[0] + A[1] + A[2] + A[3] + A[4] + A[5] + A[6] = 0
```

and there are no elements with indices greater than 7.

P = 8 is not an equilibrium index, because it does not fulfill the condition 0 ≤ P < N.

Now i have to write a function:

```
int solution(int A[], int N);
```

that, given a zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers, returns any of its equilibrium indices. The function should return −1 if no equilibrium index exists.

For example, given array A shown above, the function may return 1, 3 or 7, as explained above.

Assume that:

```
N is an integer within the range [0..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647].
```

here have some Complexity:

```
Elements of input arrays can be modified.
```

Comment: One way is to go through each element in turn and sum up the elements to the left and right of it, and see if the left and right sums are equal: if they are, that's an equilibrium point, and you can stop; otherwise, move onto the next element and try again. Try implementing that first. It won't be efficient for large N, but it is a start.

Comment: because Elements of input arrays can be modified. that's why  we don't need to specifically limit of the array

Comment: Start with a left and right sum.  The left starts at zero and the right is the sum of the items from index 1 to N-1.  Loop through the array from 1 to N-2 and add the N-1 value to the left and subtract the N+1 value to the right.  Check if they are equal.  If so return N else keep going.  You'll also need to check if the initial right sum is 0 at the beginning and return 0 or if the left sum is 0 at the end and return N-1.

Comment: Which language?  For example, Java has ArrayList, but C and C++ don't. The language determines what data structures can be easily used.

Comment: **Stack Overflow is not a coding service for ordering code.** Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take a [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Show us what you've tried so far and what problem you're facing with that so that we can find out the problem and suggest a correction(if any) and maybe even provide a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

100 Score in Javascript

```
function solution(V) {

    var sum = 0;
    for (i=0; i < V.length; i++) {
      sum += V[i];   
    }

    var leftSum= 0;
    var rightSum = 0;

    for (j=0; j < V.length; j++) {
      rightSum = sum - (leftSum + V[j]);
      if(leftSum == rightSum) {
          return j;
      }
      leftSum += V[j];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

100% scored with c#

```
using System;
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // First calculate sum of complete array as `sum_right`
        long sum_right = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            sum_right += A[i];
        }

        // start calculating sum from left side (lower index) as `sum_left`
        // in each iteration subtract A[i] from complete array sum - `sum_right`
        long sum_left = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < A.Length; p++)
        {
            sum_left += p - 1 < 0 ? 0: A[p-1];
            sum_right -= A[p];
            if (sum_left == sum_right)
            {
                 return p;
            }
        }
        return -1;


    }
}
```

Comment: A little explanation would surely boost the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 6):

100% - Java

```
int solution(int A[], int N) {

    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        sum += (long) A[i];
    }
    long leftSum = 0;
    long rightSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        rightSum = sum - (leftSum + A[i]);
        if (leftSum == rightSum) {
            return i;
        }
        leftSum += A[i];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

In C++ (because that was one of the original tags, though it looks like it has been removed...)

```
int solution(int a[], int N){
    int left;
    int right;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        left  = 0;
        right = 0;
        for(int t = 0; t < N; t++){
            if(t < i)      left  += a[t];
            else if(t > i) right += a[t];
            else continue;
        }
        if(left == right) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

...

int demo[] = {-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1};
cout << solution(demo,sizeof(demo)/sizeof(*demo));
```

if you want to see all the indices...

```
if(left == right) cout << "Equilibrium Index: " <<  i << endl;
```

I find it odd it doesn't need to return an array of indices; that said, should you need it that's not too hard to implement with some slight modification

Answer (score 3):

The answer is posted in this blog: http://blog.codility.com/2011/03/solutions-for-task-equi.html. In order to avoid O(N^2) and achieve O(N) performance:
The key observation for better running time is to update the left/right sums in constant time instead of recomputing them from the scratch.

```
int equi(int arr[], int n) 
{
    if (n==0) return -1; 
    long long sum = 0;
    int i; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) sum+=(long long) arr[i]; 

    long long sum_left = 0;    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        long long sum_right = sum - sum_left - (long long) arr[i];
        if (sum_left == sum_right) return i;
        sum_left += (long long) arr[i];
    } 
    return -1; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the java equivalent

```
public static int equilibriumIndex(int[] array) {
    int INDEX_NOT_FOUND = -1;
    int rSum = 0, lSum = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        rSum += array[index];           
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        lSum += (index==0) ? 0 : array[index -1];// cumulative sum before (left sum) the current index
        rSum -= array[index]; // sum after (right sum) the current index onwards
        if (lSum == rSum) { // if both sums, cumulative sum before the current index and cumulative sum after the current index is equal, we got the equilibrium index 
            return index;
        }                       
    }
    return INDEX_NOT_FOUND;
}
```

Here is how you would test it

```
@Test
public void equilibriumTest() {
    int result = ArrayUtils.equilibriumIndex(new int[]{1,2,3,1,6});
    assertThat(result, equalTo(3));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward approach looks the following way.

First of all you need to calculate the sum of all elements of the array

For example if you have the array in C++

```
int a[] = { -1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1 };
```

then you can use an ordinary loop to calculate the sum or standard algorithm `std::accumulate` declared in header `<numeric>`

For example

```
long long int right_sum = 
    std::accumulate( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), 0ll );
```

The sum of the elements of the left subsequence initially is equal to zero

```
long long int left_sum = 0;
```

Then you can apply standard algorithm `std::find_if` with an appropriate lambda-expression or again write an ordinary loop as for example

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ )
{
    right_sum -= a[i];
    if ( left_sum == right_sum ) std::cout << i << ' ';
    left_sum += a[i];
}
```

The result will be

```
1 3 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic programming approach. O(N) time. O(2N) space.

1. Keep two tables (arrays), tableBefore and tableAfter.
2. tableBefore has sum up to index i for every i; i -> 1 to N.
3. tableAfter has sum up to index i for every i; i -> N to 1.
4. Afterwards loops and compare every index in tableBefore and tableAfter. If it's equal, that's your equilibrium index.

   ```
   public static int EquilibriumIndex2(int[] a) {
   int len = a.length;
   int[] tableBefore = new int[len];
   int[] tableAfter = new int[len];

   tableBefore[0] = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
       tableBefore[i] = tableBefore[i - 1] + a[i - 1];
   }

   //System.out.println("tableBefore: " + Arrays.toString(tableBefore));
   tableAfter[len - 1] = 0;
   for (int i = len - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
       tableAfter[i] = tableAfter[i + 1] + a[i + 1];
   }
   //System.out.println("tableAfter: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(tableAfter));

   for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
       if (tableAfter[j] == tableBefore[j]) {
           return j;
       }
   }
   return -1;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sums approach to solve this. Whenever sum from left = sum from right, you have an equilibrium point.

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    int[] sumLeft = new int[A.length];
    int[] sumRight = new int[A.length];

    sumLeft[0] = A[0];
    sumRight[A.length-1] = A[A.length-1];
    for (int i=1; i<A.length; i++){
        sumLeft[i] = A[i] + sumLeft[i-1];
    }
    for (int i=A.length-2; i>=0; i--) {
        sumRight[i] = sumRight[i+1] + A[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        if (sumLeft[i]==sumRight[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer in Swift 3.0

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {

var nElements = A.count
var equilibriumIndexArray = [Int]() /* to store all possible indices */
var equilibriumIndex = -1

for fixedIndex in 0..<nElements{

    var sumLeft = 0
    var sumRight = 0

    //Sum the left part
    for index in 0..<fixedIndex
    {
        sumLeft += A[index]
    }

    //Sum the right part
    for index in fixedIndex+1..<nElements
    {
        sumRight += A[index]
    }

    //Check for equilibrium
    if sumLeft == sumRight
    {
        equilibriumIndexArray.append(fixedIndex)
    }

}

//pick a random element from the list of possible answers
if equilibriumIndexArray.count > 0
{
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(equilibriumIndexArray.count)))
    equilibriumIndex = equilibriumIndexArray[randomIndex]
}

return equilibriumIndex
```

}

Answer (score 1):

in python :)

```
def solution(A):
    INDEX_NOT_FOUND = -1
    right_sum = 0 
    left_sum = 0

    for item in range(0, len(A)):
        right_sum += A[item]

    for item in range(0, len(A)):
        if item == 0:
            left_sum +=  0 
        else: 
            left_sum += A[item -1]
        right_sum -= A[item]
        if left_sum == right_sum:
            return item
    return INDEX_NOT_FOUND;
```

Answer (score 1):

**100% - PHP**

```
function solution(array $a)
{
    $result = [];

    for($i = 0; $count = count($a), $i < $count; $i++) {
        if(sumLeft($a, $i-1) === sumRight($a, $i+1)) {
            $result[] = $i;
        }
    }

    return  count($result) ? $result : -1;
}

function sumRight(array $a, int $position): int
{
    return array_sum(array_slice($a, $position));;
}

function sumLeft(array $a, int $position): int
{
    return array_sum(array_slice($a, 0, $position + 1));
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(solution([-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 1]));
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution :
steps :

1) Check (Array = null)

Then Print “No Equilibrium point present as the array is NULL”

2) Check (length of Array = 1)

Then Print "Equilibrium_Index = 0" => Only single element present in array which is the equilibrium point

3) Check (Length of Array > 1)

Loop (Array Index 1 to Length-1)

Consider each index as equilibrium point

Check (sum of elements below equilibrium point = sum of elements above equilibrium poin)

Yes => equilibrium_index = i (break the loop)

No => continue step 3 with next value of loop counter

4) if control is not returned from step 3 means the equilibrium point is not present in loop

Then Print "No equilibrium point present in array."

Please find below code for same :

```
 public int findSum(int equillibrium,int a[],int flag)
 {


      /*Flag - It represents whether sum is required for left side of equilibrium 
       point or right side of equilibrium point
      *Flag = 0 => Sum is required for left side of equilibrium point
      *Flag = 1 => Sum is required for right side of equilibrium point
      */

     int lowlimit = 0, uplimit = a.length-1, i ,sum = 0;

     if(flag==0)
         uplimit = equillibrium - 1;
     else
         lowlimit = equillibrium + 1;

     for(i=lowlimit ; i<=uplimit; i++)
         sum = sum + a[i];

     return sum;
 }

 public int findEquillibriumPoint(int a[])
 {
     int i = 0; //Loop Counter

     //Since only one element is present it is at equilibrium only and index of equillibrium point is index of single element i.e 0
     if(a.length==1)
         return 0;
     else
     {
         for(i=1;i<a.length;i++)
         {
             if(findSum(i,a,0)==findSum(i,a,1)) //checking if some of lower half from equilibrium point is equal to sum of upper half
                 return i; //if equilibrium point is found return the index of equilibrium point
         }
     }

     return -1;//if equilibrium point is not present in array then return -1 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the lazy ones and PHP developers:

```
$A = [];
$A[0] = -1;
$A[1] =  3;
$A[2] = -4;
$A[3] =  5;
$A[4] =  1;
$A[5] = -6;
$A[6] =  2;
$A[7] =  1;

echo solution($A) . "\n";

function solution($A)
{
    $sum = 0;

    for ($i=0; $i < count($A); $i++) {
        $sum += $A[$i];
    }

    $sumRight = 0;
    $sumLeft = 0;

    for ($j=0; $j < count($A); $j++) {
        $sumRight = $sum - ($sumLeft + $A[$j]);
        if ($sumLeft == $sumRight) {
            return $j;
        }
        $sumLeft += $A[$j];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Complexity `O(N)`

Answer (score 0):

100 Score in Ruby

```
def equilibrium(a)
  sum = 0
  n = a.length
  left_sum = 0
  right_sum = 0

  n.times do |i|
    sum += a[i]
  end

  n.times do |i|
    right_sum = sum - left_sum - a[i]
    if right_sum == left_sum
      return i
    end
    left_sum += a[i]
  end
  return -1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully tested C#

```
using System;


class Program
{
    static int Function1(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        int i, j;
        int leftsum;
        int rightsum;
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {

            leftsum = 0;

            rightsum = 0;

            if(i == 0)
            {
                leftsum = 0;
                
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    rightsum += arr[j];
                }

                if (leftsum == rightsum)
                    return i;

            }
            
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    leftsum += arr[j];

                }
           

            if (n-1 != j)
            {
                for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                {
                    rightsum += arr[j];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rightsum = arr[n-1];
            }

            if (leftsum == rightsum)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = { 1, 5, -8, 0, -2 };
        int arr_size = arr.Length;

        Console.Write(Function1(arr, arr_size));
    }
}
```