# How to find an element in array such that sum of left array is equal to sum of right array

Tags: c++, arrays, turbo-c++

here is the input and output the code should generate:

- Input : `1 4 2 5 0`
- Output : `2`

Explanation : If 2 is the partition, then: `1+ 4=5(LHS)` and `5+0=5(RHS)` should print `2`, but in my case I'm not getting the output.

I tried my code with the logic that.. the n-th element would be present somewhere in between the array. So considering the sum of element of arr till n-th element will be LHS and from n-th element it would be till the end of the arr which is RHS. Also i added a while loop which increments the pointing element n.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main(){
   int arr[5],arr2[5],i,j=0,k=0,n=1;
   cout<<"input_arr\n";
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];

   while(n<=5)
{
   for(i=n;i<5;n++)
      j+=arr[i];   //sum of right side arr from n-th   element
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    k+=arr2[i];  //sum of left side arr till n-th element
   if(k==j)
    cout<<"\n"<<arr[n];  // prints the equilbrium element
   else
         n++;
}
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Before you get too much further, giv [Why doesn't a simple “Hello World”-style program compile with Turbo C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863062/why-doesnt-a-simple-hello-world-style-program-compile-with-turbo-c) a read so that you have some awareness of the sorts of problems you will likely run into using Turbo C++.

Comment: Obligatory reminder: Turbo C++ is horribly outdated, you should switch to a modern compiler...

Comment: On the upside TurboC++ comes with the fantastic Turbo Debugger, a tool that will allow you to control the execution of your program and investigate its variables. This makes it much easier to see what the program is really doing (as opposed to what you want it to do). Note that the vast majority of modern toolchains also come with a debugger.

Comment: I won't give the full answer but you can achieve this with a single while (or do-while) loop where you accumulate a sum from both the beginning and end of your array - i.e. you don't need any `for` loops here, just think about what condition you need for your `while` loop.

Comment: This looks a little funky: `for(i=n;i<5;n++)
      j+=arr[i];`

Comment: This is called an Equilibrium Index and there are lots of [examples here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375769/a-zero-indexed-array-given-an-equilibrium-index-of-this-array) and at [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Equilibrium_index).

Comment: FWIW, A modern approach would look like: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/542244cf4ecf27f7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you want to reset j, k every iteration with this method, if I understand correctly.

Second, the second for loop increments n instead of i, for some reason.

Third, you're also declaring arr2, not initializing it, and adding values in arr2 to k for some reason.

You're including the median as well. Try n = 2.

j = arr[2] + arr[3]+arr[4] = 2 + 5 + 0 = 7
k = arr[0] + arr[1] = 1 +  4 = 0

proposed changes to while loop (to maintain the same method):

```
while (n <= 5) {
    j = 0; k = 0;
    for (i = n+1; i < 5; i++) {
        j+= arr[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        k+= arr[i]
    }
    if (k == j) {
        cout << "\n" << arr[n];
        break; //you should end the for loop here
    }
    n++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some hints that should guide you to the solution:

1. Calculate total sum in the array in one pass. Let's call it *totalSum*.
2. Do a second pass and calculate the *partialSum*, until the position that you have processed (**but not included**). Say that this is *i*, with value *a[i]*. If `totalSum - partialSum - a[i] = partialSum`, then the position *i* is your answer, and *a[i]* is its value.

Answer (score 0):

When you're summing the right side of the array, you're starting at the equilibrium element:

let's assume `n = 2` and your input is `[1, 4, 2, 5, 0]`

```
while(n<=5) {
  for(i=n;i<5;n++)
      j+=arr[i];   //sum of right side arr from n-th   element
}
```

the summation of the right side of the array will start at `i = 2`, thus it will be `2 + 5 + 0` not `5 + 0`.

A quick and easy way to debug problems like this is to print what each step is doing (in your case, what index it's picking to sum) so you can quickly diagnose if you're doing something you're not supposed to.

Also, your current method isn't the most optimal approach but it's a good place to begin. I urge you to try a different approach after you get this solution to work.